# SMTP host/port values for Microsoft Exchange using JavaMail API in Android

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail, hostname, microsoft-exchange

What are the smtp **host**, smtp **port**, smtp **socketfactory port** for sending emails using a Microsoft Exchange mail account?

I have referred to this amazing tutorial right [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/) but it is only applicable for sending emails using google accounts. So the snippet of code below shows the configuration properties for gmail.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.".smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

So what are the values that I should write instead if I want to send emails using my MS Exchange account?

Comment: [We can't tell you that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#whichserver).  Also, [you don't need the socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaMail does not provide a mail server for you to use. You must use your **own mail server**, or one **provided by your Internet Service Provider** or **the company** you work for. Your network administrator can give you the information necessary to configure JavaMail to work with your mail server.

Reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#whichserver

Thanks for this, [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon)